# Visual Studio for Mac how to collapse regions and methods

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I couldn't find a way to collapse/expand regions and sections from Visual Studio for Mac.

If someone could share how to do that, it would be very useful.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to go to `Preferences >> Text Editor >> General` as on the image below and you will see Code Folding area.

[image: Visual Studio for Mac Code Folding area]

You can check whatever you need and you will see code folding blocks in your code.

Comment: on regular VS i used to "CTRL+M+O" to collapse all... is there a bind on VS for mac?

Comment: on mine (VS for Mac 8.8.10) it is shift + option + command + [. That toggles all collapse it isn't exactly the same as it is in VS on Windows.

Answer (score 12):

For VS for Mac, Menu > Edit > Outlining...

Click a menu selection.

Note - Your cursor has to be clicked inside a code file before you nav to menu item or they will be grayed out.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: i typed folding but no thing show

Answer (score 12):

Yes.. You can follow this key patterns to collapse and expand all the methods.

```
Shift + Option + Command + ArrowDown
```

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd>  +  <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⬇</kbd>

OR Follow the Image Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of 15 Feb 2024, the key binding that worked for collapsing all regions (macOS Sonoma, 14.0; Visual Studio Code version: 1.84.2) was <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>. To open all regions, use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> followed by <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.